# how to know which features contribute more in the class labels

Tags: correlation, python, pandas

I have a data of million record, and each record has a label the sum of all labels in my data is 324521 label. I don't want to do classification; I want only to know which features contribute more in having this label? I mean which features are more indicator in deciding the label of the record; These features are both categorical and numerical. How can I do this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you want to see which features **individually** (not collectively) point to the existence of each label, right?

What I'd do in this case is to first one-hot encode the labels so that you get N columns, each one signifying the existence of a specific label.
Then a simple criterion like [Gini Impurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Gini_impurity) or [Information Gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Information_gain) (or more properly referred to as
[KL-divergenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)) should do the trick. These are the criterions that Decision Trees use. Basically you want to see what feature leads to a better separation of the values in each one of the labels.